# How can you define a path handler before an include?

Tags: php

I have some files that need to be included but are outside the scope of the project, so they need to be outside class scope.

I want to change this:

```
include_once("/my/path/to/the/file");
```

to something like this:

```
include_once(getEnvironmentSpecificPath());
```

Every developer has their own file structure and relative path, and the file is used across multiple classes. So I tried defining my custom path in a .env and wrote a method that finds the file, but since I can't call a static method before a class scope, I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: if you can relate the path you can use something `../` to navigate outside of your project

Comment: the folders before the project are system specific, it's not practical to use that method since every dev will have to put in their own filepath everytime.

Comment: Then do a soft link to your working directory, so all the developers can put the folder somewhere, but softlink it

Comment: Including a global function would just be easier, instead of asking everyone to do a symbolic link, do you see my thought process ?

Comment: humm.. maybe then keep a file `env.php` with some configuration like `$config['file_path'] = "path to file";` and then import it first and then do `include_once($config['file_path']);`.

Answer (score 0):

Create an external file to be included, like a config.php.
Define constants in that file, with their own value, and include that file.
Do something like this:

```
define("enviroment_path", "/your/path/goes/here");
```

Once included, you can use
enviroment_path
as variable.